# The teacher , teacher, the students, students

Tags: articles, definite-articles

The following is a quotation from a book entitled  *Teaching English as a Second Language*:

> The teacher is viewed as a knowledge provider  and the students as the receivers of knowledge , and the teaching  as  a process of transmitting knowledge from teacher to students. (Wu & Fang, 2002)

I have understood the whole sentence  and the author is talking about how teachers and students are  viewed in the teaching learning process.

In the beginning of the quotation, they used the definite article  before the word *teacher* because they are considering the teacher as  a class of people, but the use of article *the* before  *students* makes them particular, and the omission of the article before the second *teacher* is incomprehensible to me .

I could understand the omission of article before the word *students* as meaning students in general

Since the authors are established educationists,I think they used them deliberately.

I would like to know about the use of articles in the passage

Comment: A problem is that there are different pulls here. 'The teacher is viewed as a knowledge provider and the student as the receiver of knowledge' is better balanced, but loses the single classroom visualisation.  The articles are not needed after the preposition. // 'Rules' sadly are only approximations to explaining real English. There are so many exceptions (as here: I'd write identically) that one often wonders about the wisdom in promoting them. How to learn idiomatic English? Get immersed in it for 60 years or so (and moan every time it changes).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Moan every time it changes? Only if you want to be called a "grammar nazi"!